# Applescript to sort files into the correct locations based on name?

Tags: applescript

I generally rip my DVD collection to my media server as I purchase new ones and I decided I would like to use Applescript to help move my completed rips to their respective homes. I sort my movies by name with a different folder based on the beginning letter of the movie. For example, if the movie title was Deadpool, it would get placed in the folder named "D".

> [My Book 2TB/Movies/D/Deadpool (2016).mkv]

I would like to be able to drop all my .mkv files into a "watchfolder" and use Folder Actions to automatically have the script put them in their places. This is what I have so far, but it is not currently working. How might I get this working?

```
 set theFolder to ((path to desktop) as text) & "Movie Rip Drop"
 set theFiles to every item of theFolder

 on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles
     repeat with aFile in theFiles
         tell application "Finder"
             if aFiles's name begins with "A" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:A"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "B" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:B"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "C" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:C"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "D" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:D"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "E" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:E"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "F" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:F"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "G" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:G"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "H" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:H"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "I" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:I"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "J" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:J"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "K" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:K"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "L" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:L"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "M" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:M"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "N" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:N"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "O" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:O"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "P" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:P"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "Q" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:Q"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "R" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:R"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "S" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:S"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "The" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:The"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "T" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:T"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "U" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:U"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "V" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:V"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "W" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:W"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "X" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:X"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "Y" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:Y"

             else if aFiles's name begins with "Z" then
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:Z"

             else
                 move aFile to "My Book 2TB:Movies:#"

             end if
         end tell
     end repeat
 end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, code outside a folder action event handler is never executed.

The shell command `ditto` can copy items and create intermediate directories simultaneously.

So get the first letter of the filename, copy the item and delete it in the hot folder

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        tell application "System Events" to set fileName to name of aFile
        if fileName starts with "The" then
            set subFolderName to "THE"
        else
            set subFolderName to first character of fileName
            set characterID to id of subFolderName
            if (characterID < 65 or characterID > 90) then set subFolderName to "#"
        end if
        set destination to quoted form of ("/Volumes/My Book 2TB/Movies/" & subFolderName & "/" & fileName)
        do shell script "usr/bin/ditto " & quoted form of POSIX path of aFile & space & destination
        do shell script "/bin/rm " & quoted form of POSIX path of aFile
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simpler way. :) Although when initialLetter is a number, how might I get it to deliver them to the directory named "#" instead of eventually ending up with directories "1" "2", etc? I also want to route any movie titles beginning with "The" to a directory named "THE".

Comment: This worked, but I had to use an OR here: if (characterID < 65 and characterID > 90)